# Most elegant solution to copy only selected rows from a large amount of text based on cell fill colour

Tags: vba, excel

I have run into issues creating an application for use in my workplace. The workbook is composed of a varying number of similar subsheets and one summary sheet. Each subsheet has 70 predefined areas for user text entry, though normally the majority of these would not be used. Any text entered by a user cause the cells in which it is entered conditionally formatted one of three colours.

I'm attempting to write a macro which will copy sequentially all of the user entered text in the subsheets into a list in the summary sheet. I intially thought that the best way to do this was to copy all user entered text and then delete the entire row of any text which didn't match the desired criteria. However, having written a macro which loops through all sheets and copies all the user entered text quickly correctly I've discovered that the formatting is not carried through. I therefore cannot delete the rows based on their format. (I've been using the basic copying method below)

```
.Range(x, x).Copy Worksheets("Summary Sheet").Cells(x, x)
```

Should I either: 
A) Modify my code to check and copy row by row only the text in the subsheets that matches my criteria 
B) Use a PasteSpecial command instead of the simpler copy command I have been using (see above) and then delete rows based on their formatting as previously intended
C) Some other method?

What is the most elegant solution? To clarify, I am primarily concerned about the load on my computer that any given solution would require and thus the ultimate speed of execution. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: This question requires an opinionated answer and is not proper for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm asking for an opinion rooted in fact, qualifying ' most elegant' as most efficient in terms of speed of execution.

Comment: Well at least two people with enough rep points to close this question agree with me.  Questions like these are better suited for code review than Stack overflow.

Comment: OK, apologies. I'll re-think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to asp8811's answer, to write elegant, fast code in Excel VBA, you should seek to minimize your use of the Range object and especially the Range.Copy method. Something like the following is preferable to Range.Copy:

```
Dim vCopy As Variant, vPaste As Variant
vCopy = IteratingSheet.UsedRange.Value
If vCopy(a, b) = ConditionalFormattingCriteria Then
    vPaste(x, y) = vCopy(a, b)
End If

With SummarySheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(vPaste), UBound(vPaste, 2))).Value = vPaste
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go the easy route and do a nested loop to check the cells in used rows and columns on each page for formatting, then use a counter (n=n+1) to paste whatever information you find to row(n) on the summary sheet. That way, you are not deleting any rows.

Use an If statement on Range("CR").Interior.ColorIndex to check if the color matches what you're looking for. You could also use a Select Case for multiple colors.

Comment: IIRC, Range.Interior.ColorIndex does not work on conditionally formatted colors.

Comment: You are correct. I've never used it for conditional formatting and had no idea. Thanks.